# Android Studio Weight Sum Bug?

Tags: android, android-layout

In Android Studio 1.5.1 it appears there is a bug with the weightSum property but I want to make sure this isn't intended behavior.

Example

1. I create a horizontal linear layout and *explicitly* give it a weightSum of 4.
2. I then place 3 buttons inside that linear layout and set the width of each to 0dp.
3. I set the first button to have a weight of 2, and the other 2 buttons to each have a weight of 1
4. The result is that the first button pushes the other buttons nearly off the screen
5. If I remove the weightSum of the linear layout that I explicitly entered, the buttons immediately line up exactly as expected (2/4, 1/4, 1/4)

I spent 2 hours trying to figure this out so I really must know if this is a bug or not. The Android documentation does not mention weightSum behaving differently when entering the value.

Comment: Literally never use WeightSum, work without it, you do not need it. It has caused me too many headaches.

Comment: There must be something else going on in your layout. Can you post it?

Comment: @mjp66 I can literally create ANY new project with these settings and it occurs. This is reproducible every time 100% with any configuration